# Python Api to delete doc_type in Elasticsearch

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search, trying below this please help.
Need to delete doctype from elasticsearch index using python API.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
es.indices.create(index="my_index")

es.index(index="my_index",doc_type="some_type1",id=101, body={'name':'Jack1'})
es.index(index="my_index",doc_type="some_type1",id=102, body={'name':'Jack2'})
es.index(index="my_index",doc_type="some_type1",id=103, body={'name':'Jack3'})
es.index(index="my_index",doc_type="some_type1",id=104, body={'name':'Jack4'})

es.index(index="my_index",doc_type="some_type2",id=101, body={'name':'Jack1'})
es.index(index="my_index",doc_type="some_type2",id=102, body={'name':'Jack2'})
es.index(index="my_index",doc_type="some_type2",id=103, body={'name':'Jack3'})
es.index(index="my_index",doc_type="some_type2",id=104, body={'name':'Jack4'})
```

After running above code I can see below data in elasctic search.

[image]

Now i have created two doc_type : some_type1 and some_type2.
I wanted to deleted some_type2 doctype from elastic search by using below line:

```
es.indices.delete(index="my_index",doc_type="some_type2")
```

But I am getting this error:
[image]

Can anybody please help me, how to delete doctype from index using python API.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited your question to fix the embedded Images. I saw 2 additional image-links without any references, should this be so?

Comment: The `delete` method doesn't take any `doc_type` argument, it can only delete a whole index, not a specific document type. As of ES 2.0, [deleting doc types is forbidden](https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring#delete-mappings) you have to delete the index and re-create it.

Answer (score 0):

*delete* method doesn't need *doc_type*. You have to add *id* which will be deleted.

For example:

```
es.delete(index="posts", id=2) # delete id=2
es.indices.delete(index='posts', ignore=[400, 404]) # remove all records
```